# Ember.js 1.0-pre4 + jQ UI sortable + localstorage adapter

Tags: ember.js

Day 2 learning ember.js...

I'm working on a offline app that needs to save draggable/sortable tile positions to localstorage, and if there is no existing data, load & save from a fixture.

**Using**: ember 1.0.0-pre4, ember-data rev11, ember-localstorage-adapter, jQ 1.9, jQ UI 1.9
https://github.com/rpflorence/ember-localstorage-adapter

It's working, but I'm a bit of a novice, feel it's not pretty and could use some community advice.
http://jsfiddle.net/Nsbcu/4/

**Questions**

1. What is the proper way to check if your `DS.Store` has loaded and is empty? My method of looking directly at `localstorage` didn't feel right.
2. After I `createRecords` from the `App.Tile.DEFAULTS` I feel I should commit them, but an error is thrown. I don't have to commit the known defaults, but curious what causes the error and how I should go about committing properly. Also is the App.ready() callback the right place for loading defaults? Error only happens when `localstorage` is empty

   `Uncaught Error: Attempted to handle event loadedData on <App.Tile:ember231:1> while in state rootState.loaded.created.inFlight. Called with undefined`
3. On the `TilesController` I'm using `sortProperties` which works great until jQ UI Sortable changes the DOM and Ember wants to update my tile order, before I get a chance to `set` the new `order`. My current solution is to turn off `sortProperties` temporarily while updating the model. Again this feels hacky, suggestions on proper way to do this?

=== Edit Feb 3 ===

If I do an async commit the initial error in question #2 is avoided.

```
App.TilesRoute = Ember.Route.extend({
    model: function() {
        return App.Tile.find();
    },
    setupController: function(controller) {
        if (localStorage.getItem('fusion-emberjs') == null) {
            App.Tile.DEFAULTS.forEach(function(item) {
                App.Tile.createRecord(item);
            });

            // Commit async, else generates error
            var _this = this;
            setTimeout(function() {
                _this.store.commit();
            }, 1);
        }
    }
});
```

Answer (score 0):

- I would put any initial code inside the application or the index Route within the setupController method

  ```
  if (localStorage.getItem('fusion-emberjs') == null) {
      App.Tile.DEFAULTS.forEach(function(item) {
          App.Tile.createRecord(item);
      });

      //*** WARNING: Generates Error ***/
      App.Tile.find().get('store').commit();
  }
  ```
- Once you move the code inside the route, replace `App.Tile.find().get('store').commit();` by `App.store.commit()` inside your route
- Create your own transaction instead of using the default one, each time you make a call to the store directly you're using the default transaction. You can create a transaction this way

> ```
> var transaction = App.store.transaction()
> transaction.createRecord(App.Foo);
> transaction.commit()
> transaction.rollback();
> ```

- Any call to App.store assumes you already created a store, right now you're only extending the `DS.Store`. Try instead

> ```
> App.Store = DS.Store.create({
>   revision: 11,
>   adapter: 'App.LSAdapter'
> });
> ```

- I would suggest that you do any event handling or transaction management in the router unless it's purely for styling or animation. In that case, the view is the right place for it. I like the router to orchestrate communication between all the assets (controllers, routes, models, views)
- A good pattern to remember is a view talks only to a controller, a controller is a mere proxy to a model, a router orchestrates communication between controllers and manages routes.

Comment: Thanks for the great advice Ken! Moved the setup code to the appropriate router. I still get the `loadedData` event error using either implicit or explicit `transaction`. I get a method not found on `DS.Store.create()` which is odd because it's mentioned throughout the code comments, but can't find it in code (ember-data.js rev11). Leaving the question open for now, hoping for input on error and the `sortProperties` butting heads with jQ UI sortable(). Updated fiddle http://jsfiddle.net/Nsbcu/3/